# I am not able access functions of a context in react.createContext()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have created a UserContext, when i try to use `setUser` it was throwing  error like this  `ERROR    TypeError: setUser is not a function. (In 'setUser(text)', 'setUser' is undefined)`

**App.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {UserContext, ContexProvider}  from './UserProvider'

export default function App(){
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
  const {error, setError} = useContext(UserContext);
  
return(
  <ContexProvider>
  <View>
    <TextInput
    onChangeText ={text =>{setUser(text)}}
    value={user}
    placeholder='User name'
    />
    <Text>{user}</Text>
  </View>
  </ContexProvider>)
}
```

**UserProvider.js**

```
import React,{createContext, useState} from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext({})

export const ContexProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] =  useState(null)
    

    return(
        <UserContext.Provider 
        value ={{
            user, 
            setUser, 
            error, 
            setError
        }}>
            {children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The context provider needs to be farther up the component tree than the context consumer. You're doing the opposite: consuming it in App, but providing it lower in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { UserContext, ContexProvider } from './UserContext';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContexProvider>
      <Child />
    </ContexProvider>
  );
}

const Child = () => {
  const { user, setUser, error, setError } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setUser(text);
        }}
        value={user}
        placeholder="User name"
      />
      <Text>{user}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/trusting-chocolate)